# G mail API for Sending Mail with attachment is failing when recipients name is in multi byte character

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-api, google-workspace

I am using below APi to send mail with attachment

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?uploadType=multipart
```

which is working fine when recipients name is in English, but if recipients name contains multi-byte(e.g Japanese), I am getting 400(Bad request) as response.

## Code snippet

```
def create_raw():

    message['to'] = ','.join([recipients_dict['name']+ 
    <"+recipients_dict['email_address']+">" for recipients_dict in 
    recipients['to']])
    message['from'] = email_address
    message['subject'] = subject
    msg = MIMEText(body)
    message.attach(msg)
```

When `recipients_dict['name']` is "English" the API works as expected, but for multi-byte character

> getting HTTP 400(Bad request) Error

.

Answer (score 1):

You have a good approach over the Gmail API. The only step necessary is to encode the string into [UTF-8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629) before sending it in bytes over [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) (due to the definition of [MIME](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045)). You can accomplish that using a code similar to:

```py
import base64
…
recipients_dict['name'] = base64.b64encode(u'ジョージ'.encode("utf-8"))
```

If you still have any question, please do not hesitate to ask for further help.

Comment: Thanks for the response but, after modifying like above some encoded/junk characters is seen when checked 'sent' tab of gmail(browser) e.g "5ZCN5YmN44OG44K544OI"

Comment: Code Snippet after modofication:
import base64
...
message['to'] = ','.join([(base64.b64encode(recipients_dict['name'].encode('utf-8'))).decode('utf-8')+" <"+recipients_dict['address']+">" for recipients_dict in recipients['to']])